# OpenCv using an IP camera photo

Tags: android, python, opencv, ip-camera

I am trying to work in opencv with a photo that I took with the Android IP camera (http://192.168.0.10:8080/shot.jpg), but it doesnt work, I get a blank window.
I tried with another image (http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/_*cb20110420175105/agallas/es/images/thumb/1/11/Agallas-el-perro-cobarde-125*(1).jpg/640px-Agallas-el-perro-cobarde-125_(1).jpg) and It works perfectly. 
Why doesn't it work with the photo taken with the ip camera?

```
  import sys, cv
  import numpy as np
  #photo = "http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110420175105/agallas/es/images/thumb/1/11/Agallas-el-perro-cobarde-125_(1).jpg/640px-Agallas-el-perro-cobarde-125_(1).jpg"
  photo = "http://192.168.0.10:8080/shot.jpg"
  img=cv.CaptureFromFile( photo )
  while True: 
    frame = cv.QueryFrame(img)
    cv.ShowImage('Foto',frame)
    if cv.WaitKey(30)==27:
         break
```

Both pictures have the same dimensions

Comment: Does it work with `cv2.imread`?

Comment: I don't think the IP camera makes any difference here. Can you verify the path is absolutely correct? Can you access the photo in other way, say your internet browser?

Comment: Yes, I can see the video from my phone and I can also take pictures from the internet browser.
I tried also with:http://192.168.0.10:8080/photo.jpg and http://192.168.0.10:8080/photoaf.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be not a very efficient way to solve my problem, but it works.

```
import urllib
import cv 

urllib.urlretrieve("http://192.168.0.10:8080/shot.jpg", "foto.jpg")
imagen=cv.LoadImage('foto.jpg')
cv.ShowImage('Image',imagen)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code that I have working to stream from my phone running Android IP Camera, using Andrea Diaz's idea and python with opencv2...

```
import cv2
import urllib

while True:
    urllib.urlretrieve("http://192.168.0.10:8080/shot.jpg", "foto.jpg")
    src_image = cv2.imread('foto.jpg', 0)
    cv2.imshow('Viewer',src_image)
    # read user keyboard for 5ms, and break on any keypress.    
    if (cv2.waitKey (5) != -1):
        break;
```